# Select rows that match right side of one to many reationship in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, pdo

I have 4 tables. One for companies, one for products one for company address, and one for company directors.

The products, director and address tables are in a one to many relationship to the company table.

So one company can have many products, many addresses and many directors.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companies` (
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `product` (`product`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `directors` (
  `director_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`director_id`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `surname` (`surname`),
  KEY `dob` (`dob`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `addresses` (
  `address_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `postcode` (`postcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

INSERT INTO `companies` (`company_id`, `company_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Honda'),
(2, 'Toyota');

INSERT INTO `products` (`product_id`, `company_id`, `product`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Civic'),
(2, 1, 'Accord'),
(3, 2, 'Corolla'),
(4, 2, 'Prius'),
(5, 1, 'CRV');

INSERT INTO `directors` (`director_id`, `company_id`, `surname`, `dob`)     VALUES
(1, 1, 'Jones', '1990-09-09'),
(2, 1, 'Smith', '1980-08-08'),
(3, 2, 'Lucas', '1970-07-07'),
(4, 1, 'Kelly', '1960-06-06'),
(5, 2, 'Monty', '1950-05-05');

INSERT INTO `addresses` (`address_id`, `company_id`, `postcode`) VALUES
(6, 1, '12345'),
(7, 2, '23456'),
(8, 1, '34567'),
(9, 2, '45678'),
(10, 1, '56789');
```

Im trying to write an efficient query (using MySql / PDO) to find products for companies that match match directors (surname AND dob) and addresses (postcode).

I just want to list one matching product per row, not list every director or postcode separately.

So far I have the below query, which seems to work, but it's ugly and I suspect a ridiculous way to go about this in terms of speed and efficiency.

```
SELECT product
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN companies c USING(company_id)
WHERE :lname IN ( 
    SELECT surname 
    FROM directors d 
    WHERE c.company_id = d.company_id )
AND :dob IN ( 
    SELECT dob 
    FROM directors d 
    WHERE c.company_id = d.company_id )
AND :postcode IN ( 
    SELECT postcode 
    FROM addresses a 
    WHERE c.company_id = a.company_id )
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: working code you want to work 'better' is best posted on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would rethink your underlying data structure... I don't see how `surname`, `dob`, and `postcode` can all be used. If you have the `surname` and `dob` then you have the `company_id` via the directors table... why then do you need the `company_id` that's in the `addresses` table from the `postcode`? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: thank you @upful. not all companies will necessarily have address records and not all companies will necessarily have directors. They are 2 separate things and have to be inked to the company table, so the only way I can see to do this is through company_id

Comment: In that case you would probably use the `OR` operator instead of `AND`... so `WHERE (surname = :surname AND dob = :dob) OR postcode = :pesticide` ... also I would think it would be important to determine which company has the products that match your search, not just returning a list of products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very least, the two subqueries on `directors` can be unified by rewriting them with the `exists` operator instead of `in`. For good measures, I rewrote the entire query with this operator, although it's not strictly necessary:

```
SELECT    product
FROM      products p
LEFT JOIN companies c USING(company_id)
WHERE     EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM directors d 
                  WHERE c.company_id = d.company_id AND 
                        (:lname  = d.lanme OR :dob = d.dob)) AND
           EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM addresses a 
                   WHERE c.company_id = a.company_id AND :postcode = a.postcode)
```

Comment: Thanks Both. Very useful. This is the solution I ended up using

Answer (score 4):

Unsure why you need subqueries at all?

```
SELECT p.product FROM products p
INNER JOIN companies c USING(company_id)
INNER JOIN directors d ON d.company_id = c.company_id AND d.surname = 'Jones' AND d.dob = '1990-09-09'
INNER JOIN addresses a ON a.company_id = c.company_id AND a.postcode = '12345'
```

Or

```
SELECT p.product FROM products p
INNER JOIN companies c USING(company_id)
INNER JOIN directors d USING(company_id) 
INNER JOIN addresses a USING(company_id)
WHERE d.surname = 'Jones'
AND d.dob = '1990-09-09'
AND a.postcode = '12345'
```

If you do an EXPLAIN on these two queries, you'll see they end up the same internally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue with this is that it returns multiple rows for the same product, one for each debtor or postcode

Comment: Ahh, then you can just use DISTINCT. e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT p.product ...`